# How to get references at the end of each chapter?

Tags: bibliographies, multibib

I want to get references at the end of each chapter. references are in bib files. Please help me. I also want to write the title of each chapter.

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.25in, paperheight=9.5in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,lipsum,multibib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{abstract}
\renewenvironment{abstract}[1]
{\begin{quote}
\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\par{\bfseries Abstract.} #1}
{\medskip\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}
\end{quote}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
\setlength{\headheight}{47.0pt}
\begin{document}
\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\end{document}
```

Ch1 file

```
         \begin{abstract}
    Each chapter should be preceded   \cite{celik2009allee} ....
    \end{abstract}
      \bibliography{bibtex_1}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
```

ch2 file

```
        \begin{abstract}
        Each chapter should be preceded  \cite{guin2014spatial} ....
        \end{abstract}
          \bibliography{bibtex_2}
        \bibliographystyle{plain}
```

bibtex_1

```
@article{celik2009allee,
  title={Allee effect in a discrete-time predator--prey system},
  author={Celik, Canan and Duman, Oktay},
  journal={Chaos, Solitons \& Fractals},
  volume={40},
  number={4},
  pages={1956--1962},
  year={2009},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{gao2013dynamics,
  title={DYNAMICS OF A RATIO-DEPENDENT PREDATOR-PREY SYSTEM WITH A STRONG ALLEE EFFECT.},
  author={Gao, Yujing and Li, Bingtuan},
  journal={Discrete \& Continuous Dynamical Systems-Series B},
  volume={18},
  number={9},
  year={2013}
}
```

bibtex_2 file

```
@article{guin2014spatial,
  title={Spatiotemporal dynamics of reaction--diffusion models of interacting populations},
  author={Guin, L N and Mandal, P K},
  journal={Applied Mathematical Modelling},
  year={http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apm.2014.02.022},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
@article{freedman1979stability,
  title={Stability analysis of a predator-prey system with mutual interference and density-dependent death rates},
  author={Freedman, HI},
  journal={Bulletin of Mathematical Biology},
  volume={41},
  number={1},
  pages={67--78},
  year={1979},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Comment: See http://ctan.org/topic/bibtex-multi.

Comment: cfr I tried, read chapterbib.pdf but failed to solve the issue. please guide me.

Comment: Did you run bibtex on each bibliography file produced during initial compilation? Unlike biblatex, bibtex won't handle this automatically.

Comment: cfr yes I have.

Comment: The problem is that the references are not coming in case of two or more bib files. I want to solve the issue.

Comment: Why are you loading both the `chapterbib` and the `multibib` packages? And what's the purpose of having two separate `bib` files?

Answer (score 2):

- I removed packages not relevant to the problem.
- `book` does not have an `abstract` environment. In order to get the code to compile, I had to remove the use of the package `abstract` and substitute `\renewcommand...` for `\newcommand...`.

Problems relevant to the question:

- `http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apm.2014.02.022` is not a year and you cannot persuade bibtex to accept it as one. I made this a `url` field.
- `multibib` appears to hang compilation, probably because it does not entirely agree with `chapterbib` though I did not investigate. Instead, I removed it.
- `plain` is not compatible with author-year citations which causes `natbib` to complain. However, if you continue compilation, it is fine - it just uses numerical labels instead. You should consider using `plainnat` instead, which is `natbib`'s and will still get you numerical citations, without complaints.

Then it works fine. At least, the use of rules is weird but that's an issue with your definition of `abstract` and not anything to do with bibliographies.

## Code

```
\begin{filecontents}{ch1.tex}
  \begin{abstract}
    Each chapter should be preceded   \cite{celik2009allee} ....
  \end{abstract}
  \bibliography{bib1}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch2.tex}
  \begin{abstract}
    Each chapter should be preceded  \cite{guin2014spatial} ....
  \end{abstract}
  \bibliography{bib2}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib1.bib}
  @article{celik2009allee,
    title={Allee effect in a discrete-time predator--prey system},
    author={Celik, Canan and Duman, Oktay},
    journal={Chaos, Solitons \& Fractals},
    volume={40},
    number={4},
    pages={1956--1962},
    year={2009},
    publisher={Elsevier}
  }
  @article{gao2013dynamics,
    title={DYNAMICS OF A RATIO-DEPENDENT PREDATOR-PREY SYSTEM WITH A STRONG ALLEE EFFECT.},
    author={Gao, Yujing and Li, Bingtuan},
    journal={Discrete \& Continuous Dynamical Systems-Series B},
    volume={18},
    number={9},
    year={2013}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib2.bib}
  @article{guin2014spatial,
    title={Spatiotemporal dynamics of reaction--diffusion models of interacting populations},
    author={Guin, L N and Mandal, P K},
    journal={Applied Mathematical Modelling},
    url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.apm.2014.02.022},
    publisher={Elsevier}
  }
  @article{freedman1979stability,
    title={Stability analysis of a predator-prey system with mutual interference and density-dependent death rates},
    author={Freedman, HI},
    journal={Bulletin of Mathematical Biology},
    volume={41},
    number={1},
    pages={67--78},
    year={1979},
    publisher={Springer}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\newenvironment{abstract}[1]
{\begin{quote}
    \noindent \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}\par{\bfseries Abstract.} #1}
  {\medskip\noindent \rule{\linewidth}{.5pt}
  \end{quote}
}
\begin{document}
  \include{ch1}
  \include{ch2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mean this                         `\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=7.25in, paperheight=9.5in,bindingoffset=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LO]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm,height=1.5cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}
\setlength{\headheight}{47.0pt}
\begin{document}
\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\end{document}`

Comment: @user1942348 I've posted the code which I used. Except you should use `plainnat` rather than `plain`.

Comment: @user1942348 When you run exactly the code I posted, what happens? Put the code in a new, blank document and run `pdflatex` -> `pdflatex`. Don't add or subtract anything. We need a sanity check and that means we want to know if the reference displays OK when you run exactly the same code I run. EDIT; also, work in an otherwise empty directory. (Empty folder if you are on Windows.)

Comment: @user1942348 Not the problem but you should adjust page dimensions manually if you're using `geometry` as it won't know about the changes. Pass `headheight=47pt` as another option to `geometry` instead.

Comment: I have followed the code and steps you have suggested. But the reference places are still coming as ?.

Comment: @user1942348 And did you run `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` twice more? (I somehow forgot to include this above - sorry.)

Comment: I ran your code just now in https://www.overleaf.com and I got the result fine. But I am not getting it in my system. I am using windows xp and I got no error in running the tex files. Any suggestions please.

Comment: @user1942348 Different file names, same issue: you'd run BibTeX on the main file which is wrong with `chapterbib`: you need to run it on each included file separately.

Comment: @JosephWright Actually I run the bib files, then the tex files twice. Would you give a Minimum Working Example where I can get an error free result.

Comment: @user1942348 The archive you sent me did not have `.blg`  or `.bbl` files for the two included files: you therefore did _not_ run BibTeX on the two subfiles. You _have_ to run `bibtex ch1` and `bibtex ch2` after the initial LaTeX run.

Comment: @user1942348 This is what I asked about in my comment on your initial question i.e. did you run `bibtex` for each bibliography, as `bibtex` won't handle this automatically. The MWE in my answer gives an error-free result, but you have to compile it correctly: `pdflatex mwe.tex` -> `bibtex ch1` -> `bibtex ch2` -> `pdflatex mwe.tex` -> `pdflatex mwe.tex`.

Comment: Now I have attached the file with pdflatex mwe.tex -> bibtex ch1 -> bibtex ch2 -> pdflatex mwe.tex -> pdflatex mwe.tex rules. Sorry for repeated mail. But the problem remains same.

Comment: @user1942348 I've got the latest zip: you have _not_ run  `bibtex ch1`, you have run `latex bib1.bib`, which is wrong. I can tell this as you should have files `ch1.blg`, `chl.bbl` and so on, whereas you have `bib1.log` and so on. You are not running the right tools on the right files: until you do the right thing we can't help further. Perhaps pop into the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) to take this further.